# How to disable/enable - Confluent KAFKA Interceptor using Spring boot profile?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm writing a Spring Boot application that uses Confluent KAFKA replicator and below is my Spring boot profile

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        interceptor:
          classes: io.confluent.connect.replicator.offsets.ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor
        timestamp:
          producer:
            security:
              protocol: PLAINTEXT
            sasl:
              mechanism: NONE
```

I don't have Confluent KAFKA replicator in the lower environment - eg: Dev. So, I want a flag/profile property to disable/enable the above Confluent KAFKA Interceptor (ConsumerTimestampsInterceptor). How do I do it? Something like this

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        interceptor:
          enabled : false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create a dev profile (for example, application-dev.yaml) for your spring application, then remove the property altogether. There is no `enabled` boolean property

Also, you shouldn't need full nesting since consumer properties are flat, anyways

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        interceptor.classes: "className"
```

Comment: I don't have Confluent KAFKA replicator in the Dev environment. Would it cause any issues if I keep these properties in the application-dev.yaml and deploy it in the Dev environment?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Replicator is a Kafka Connect process, it's not something you use as part of a Spring application, anyway. I've never used those interceptors, but I don't think the "require" Replicator to be running, they just report information for Control Center lag collection